# Problem while adding elements to list in while function

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming

I'm tring to write a little bit of code that adds a missing element to a list. In specific: given a numbered data set such as:

```
{{0, 1}, {1, 6}, {2, 9}, {3, 29}, {4, 62}, {5, 97}, {6, 107}, {7, 162}, 
 {8, 178}, {9, 173}, {10, 119}, {11, 109}, {12, 49}, {13, 45},
 {14, 26}, {15, 17}, {16, 9}, {17, 6}, {18, 2}, {20, 1}}
```

If there is a value missing (such as `{19,0}` here), I want *Mathematica* to add that element. So I've written this piece of code:

```
i = 1;
While[list[[i, 1]] <= max,
 If[list[[i, 1]] != i - 1,
   Insert[list, {i - 1, 0}, i];
   ++i,
   ++i
   ];
 ]
```

Which apparently prefers not working over working. The problem I'm having is that the element does not actually get added to the list, while if I change the insert command to a print command, I get the output `{19,0}`. I'm then using this code:

```
i = 1;
While[list[[i, 1]] <= max,
 If[list[[i, 1]] != i - 1,
   Print[{i - 1, 0}];
   ++i,
   ++i
   ];
 ]
```

Is anyone able to understand why my function isn't working and what I can do to solve it?

Comment: See specifically: [(19804)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/19804#19804)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-procedural approach.

```
list = {{0, 1}, {1, 6}, {2, 9}, {4, 62}, {5, 97}, {6, 107}, {7, 
    162}, {8, 178}, {9, 173}, {10, 119}, {11, 109}, {12, 49}, {13, 
    45}, {14, 26}, {15, 17}, {16, 9}, {17, 6}, {18, 2}, {20, 1}};
```

I deleted the `{3, 29}` element for a better illustration.

```
max = Max@list[[All, 1]]
missing = Complement[Range@max, list[[All, 1]]]
```

> 20
>
> {3, 19}

```
insert = {#, 0} & /@ missing
```

> {{3, 0}, {19, 0}}

```
list~Join~insert // Sort
```

> {{0, 1}, {1, 6}, {2, 9}, {3, 0}, {4, 62}, {5, 97}, {6, 107}, {7, 
>     162}, {8, 178}, {9, 173}, {10, 119}, {11, 109}, {12, 49}, {13, 
>     45}, {14, 26}, {15, 17}, {16, 9}, {17, 6}, {18, 2}, {19, 0}, {20, 
>     1}}

Answer (score 2):

Aaaand as always you figure it out just after you ask the question. The problem is that you have to re-define the list, so the code should read:

```
i = 1;
While[list[[i, 1]] <= max,
 If[list[[i, 1]] != i - 1,
   list = Insert[list, {i - 1, 0}, i];
   ++i,
   ++i
   ];
 ]
```

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is better not to make up data?

```
lst = {{0, 1}, {1, 6}, {2, 9}, {3, 29}, {4, 62}, {5, 97}, {6, 
   107}, {7, 162}, {8, 178}, {9, 173}, {10, 119}, {11, 109}, {12, 
   49}, {13, 45}, {14, 26}, {15, 17}, {16, 9}, {17, 6}, {18, 2}, {20, 
   1}}
a = Association[Rule @@@ lst]
Lookup[a, 19, 0]
```